# Firebase Provider Name for Custom Tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible in Firebase Authentication, when dealing with custom generated tokens, in this case for example from Steam OpenID, to tell Firebase what provider it is from? (ie, when you authenticate using Email/Password you will get an envelope symbol in the Providers column, but if you have a custom token you get nothing. Was wondering if I could label my custom auths the same way the predefined ones are labeled.

[image]

Comment: Hey Sebastian, you cannot change the provider label for custom token users.